How to prove that if $u \in W_{1,p}$, then $|u| \in W_{1,p}$?
I was trying to solve this problem and many solutions approach it by breaking it. Can we directly deduce by taking an appropriate smooth function like the way we do for u+?

See how I have "latexified" your title.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433599/absolute-value-of-functions-in-sobolev-space
